# Scala For-Comprehension: How to Recover and Continue If a Future Fails

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

Given the following `List` of integers...

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3)
```

... I need to invoke 2 methods that return a `Future` on each element and obtain the following result:

```
Future(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3))
```

Here below is my try:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f1(i: Int) = Future(i)
def f2(i: Int) = Future { if (i % 2 == 0) throw new Exception else i }

val l = List(1, 2, 3)

val results = Future.sequence(l.map { i =
  val f = for {
    r1 <- f1(i)
    r2 <- f2(i) // this throws an exception if i is even
  } yield Some(r1)

  f.recoverWith {
    case e => None
  }
})
```

If `f2` fails, I want to recover and continue with the remaining elements. The code above doesn't work since `recoverWith` is never invoked, even if `f2` fails.

How do I recover when `f2` fails so that the final result is something like this?

```
Future(Some(1), None, Some(3))
```

The second element should be `None` because `f2` fails when the input integer is even (i.e. 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when `recoverWith` has output type as `Future`, it works fine.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f1(i: Int) = Future(i)
def f2(i: Int) = Future { if (i % 2 == 0) throw new Exception else i }

val l = List(1, 2, 3)

val results = Future.sequence(l.map { i =>
  val f = for {
    r1 <- f1(i)
    r2 <- f2(i) // this might throw an exception
  } yield Some(r1)

  f.recoverWith {
    case e => Future { println("Called recover " + i); None } // wrapped in Future
  }
})
results onComplete println
```

result:

```
// Called recover 2
// Success(List(Some(1), None, Some(3))       

// tried with scala version: 2.10.4
```

Answer (score 3):

`recoverWith` should return a `Future` of something, so your example won't even compile.

You can use `recover` instead

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f1(i: Int) = Future(i)
def f2(i: Int) = Future { if (i % 2 == 0) throw new Exception else i }
val l = List(1, 2, 3)

val results = Future.sequence(l.map { i =>
  val f = for {
    r1 <- f1(i)
    r2 <- f2(i) // this throws an exception if i is even
  } yield Some(r1)

  f.recover { case _ => None }
})
```

Also, in your specific example you are not even using `r2`, so you can do just

```
val results = Future.sequence(l.map { i =>
  f1(i).map(Some(_)).recover { case _ => None }
})
```